# Grub related error from software updater "Package dependencies cannot be resolved"

Tags: grub2, package-management, dependencies, update-manager

Software updates usually are problem free but I'm getting this one.
My older desktop runs Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

grub-efi-amd64-signed: Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.31) but 2.04-1ubuntu26.12 is to be installed
```

[Screenshot of system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDDOm.png)

[Screenshot of update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUNJ6.png)

```
don@Fairview:~$ sudo apt install -f
[sudo] password for don: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  adobe-flash-properties-gtk distro-info dvdrip-utils fonts-unfonts-core g++-7
  gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 gnome-software-common
  libanyevent-perl libargon2-0 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasync-interrupt-perl
  libboost-date-time1.65.1 libboost-filesystem1.65.1 libboost-iostreams1.65.1
  libboost-random1.65.1 libboost-regex1.65.1 libboost-system1.65.1
  libcbor-xs-perl libclass-accessor-perl libcomerr2:i386 libdns-export1100
  libdouble-conversion1 libevent-2.1-6 libevent-core-2.1-6
  libevent-execflow-perl libevent-perl libevent-rpc-perl libexiv2-14
  libffi6:i386 libfluidsynth1 libgfortran4 libgmime-3.0-0 libgpm2:i386
  libgspell-1-1 libgssglue1 libgtk2-ex-formfactory-perl libgtkmm-2.4-1v5
  libguard-perl libgweather-3-15 libhunspell-1.6-0 libicu60:i386 libidl-2-0
  libilmbase12 libindicator7 libintl-perl libintl-xs-perl libisc-export169
  libisl19 libiso9660-11 libjson-c3 libktoblzcheck1v5 liblcms2-2:i386
  liblinear3 libllvm10 libllvm10:i386 libllvm7 libllvm9 liblouis14
  libmicrodns0 libminiupnpc10 libmysofa0 libnfs11 libnss-myhostname
  libopenobex2 liborcus-0.13-0 libparse-debianchangelog-perl libplymouth4
  libprocps6 libprotobuf-lite10 libprotobuf10 libpsl5:i386
  libpython3.6-minimal libqpdf21 libquicktime2 libraw16 libreadline7
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-style-galaxy
  libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsane1 libsignon-glib1 libstdc++-7-dev libtidy5
  libva-glx2 libvcdinfo0 libvpx5 libwayland-egl1-mesa libwind0-heimdal:i386
  libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-environment0.1 libwinpr-file0.1 libwinpr-handle0.1
  libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwxgtk3.0-0v5 libx264-152
  libx265-146 libxine2 libxine2-bin libxine2-doc libxine2-ffmpeg
  libxine2-misc-plugins libxine2-plugins libxine2-x lsdvd nplan ogmtools
  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common plainbox-secure-policy python-attr
  python-automat python-backports.functools-lru-cache python-blinker
  python-concurrent.futures python-constantly python-dnspython
  python-fasteners python-faulthandler python-hyperlink python-monotonic
  python-musicbrainzngs python-pil python-pyasn1 python-sip python-talloc
  python-webencodings python3-bs4 python3-jinja2 python3-lxml python3-oauth
  python3-padme python3-piston-mini-client python3-soupsieve
  python3-webencodings python3-xlsxwriter python3.6-minimal qpdf qtcore4-l10n
  seahorse-daemon twolame ubuntu-web-launchers unity-scope-calculator
  unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp
  unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks unity-scope-manpages unity-scope-openclipart
  unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-virtualbox unity-scope-yelp
  unity-scope-zotero unity-scopes-runner xine-ui
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 66 not upgraded.
don@Fairview:~$ 

don@Fairview:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 h#ttp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 h#ttp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 h#ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:4 h#ttp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Ign:5 h#ttp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric InRelease                    
Get:6 h#ttp://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]
Hit:7 h#ttp://archive.canonical.com focal InRelease
Hit:8 h#ttp://archive.canonical.com bionic InRelease
Err:9 h#ttp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N] y
Get:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,098 B]                                                          
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                              
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
don@Fairview:~$
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install -f` in terminal?

Comment: Open a terminal. Run `sudo apt update`. Copy the complete output and paste it into your question above.

Comment: Terminal outputs added to question.  # inserted in links to allow posting more than so many links cause I don't have cred.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) . Remove *oneiric*, remove Google and readd it.

Comment: I got lucky without doing anything other than running the software update today.  Perhaps a problem existed that affected users similar to myself and a fix performed.  I successfully ran the software update today.  Thanks for the suggestions.